# Printing in GeoSever 2.23 not working

Tags: geoserver, printing, mapfish-print-2

I installed Geoserver 2.23 on Windows Server with Apatche Tomcat 9.0.56 and jdk-11.0.18+10.

What I can see everything works well except the printing.

With the default data-directory I clicked Demo and mapfisk printing. It does not work and retorned HTTP-error 500.

I have tried with different versions of Tomcat and different versions of java but the problems remain.

In the log I can see:

> quote
> 02 May 06:59:18 ERROR  [servlet.BaseMapServlet] - Error occurred while reading configuration file
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mapPrinter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'threadResources'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadResources': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.mapfish.print.ThreadResources] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
> context: geoserver
> delegate: false
> ----------> Parent Classloader:
> java.net.URLClassLoader@5a8e6209
> ]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)

Anyone else that have seen that and have any solutiones?

Best ragards
Johan

Comment: which version of Java are you using when you get that error? how did you install mapfish?

Comment: I was using the build in printing in GeoServer and the java-version used is "jdk-11.0.18+10" (OpenJDK).

Comment: @JohanHallgren any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion was that everything was changed to MapFish 3 and the API have changed a lot there.
Actually, I changed to MapFish as a separate installation and changed the call to that app instead.
I haven't checked with the printing in GeoServer but I will not be surprised if my code will work there also.